# Updating Access Table using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to Update a table in Access using SQL.  I need to update a column in one table to be UPDATED if a column in another table is TRUE.

I have tried writing my own code but to no avail!

```
UPDATE table1, table2
    SET table1.ReportName = "UPDATED"
    WHERE ((table1.Name=table2.name) AND ((table2.Ind)="TRUE"));
```

I get an error that says:  Data Type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

Use EXISTS:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.ReportName = 'UPDATED'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2
  WHERE table2.Name = table1.name AND table2.Ind = 'TRUE'
)
```

If the data type of `table2.Ind` is `Boolean (Yes/No)` then:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.ReportName = 'UPDATED'
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table2
  WHERE table2.Name = table1.name AND table2.Ind = TRUE
)
```